# how org-capture can insert value in an existing table line

Tags: org-capture

I am diabetic and I have to take my blood glucose three times a day (morning, noon, evening)
I can do in three separate tables, and I create a table to group the daily records.
How could I capture all three readings in one table with org-capture?

The type 'table-line' create a new table line but I want to complete an existing line for the midday and evening values.

```
   |      date         |matin|midi|soir|
   |-------------------|-----|----|----||
   | [2019-03-27 mer.] | 120 |    |    |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is done from org-caputure, maybe someone else can help you with that, but here's a command that does something similar. You have to change the file name and add `#+name: mytable` to the table.

```el
(defun log-glucose ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file "~/yourfile.org"))
    (with-current-buffer
        (pop-to-buffer (or (find-buffer-visiting file)
                           (find-file-noselect file)))
      (let ((input (read-string "Input: ")))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (when (re-search-forward "#\\+name: \\(mytable\\)" nil t)
          (goto-char (org-table-end))
          (let ((line (org-table-current-line)))
            (org-table-goto-line line)
            (cond ((string= (org-table-get line 2) "")
                   (org-table-put line 2 input t))
                  ((string= (org-table-get line 3) "")
                   (org-table-put line 3 input t))
                  ((string= (org-table-get line 4) "")
                   (org-table-put line 4 input t))
                  (t
                   (org-table-insert-row t)
                   (org-table-put (1+ line) 1 (format-time-string "[%F %a]") t)
                   (org-table-put (1+ line) 2 input t)))))))))
```